# Где скачать Zend Framework 1.0.2?

Tags: zend-framework

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где скачать Zend Framework 1.0.2, на официальном сайте вроде бы уже как нет, или я плохо смотрел:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут:

- [Latest Releases](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest);
- [Archives](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/archives);

Comment: Спасибо большое! А я искал искал....